# Drop down menu won't style

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<ul id="myMenu">
        <li><a class = "link" href='#page1' Tooltip = "Home Page">Home</a>    </li>
            <li><a href='#page2'>Teams</a></li>
            <li><a href='#page3'>Games</a>
                <ul>
                <li><a href='#page3'>CLG</a></li>
                <li><a href='#page3'>TSM</a></li>
                <li><a href='#page3'>C9</a></li>
                <li><a href='#page3'>SKT T1</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href='#page4'>Venues</a></li>
            <li><a href='#page4'>Battle</a></li>
        </ul>
```

CSS:

```
#myMenu {
    background-color: red;
    list-style-type:none;
    height:30px;
    width: 100%;
}
#myMenu li { 
    float:left; 
    text-align: center;
    width: 20%; 
}
#myMenu li a {
    padding:9px 20px;
    display:block;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#myMenu li:hover { 
    position:relative; 
    background-color: white
}

#myMenu li:hover a{ 
    color: red;
}

/* Submenu */
#myMenu ul {
    position: absolute;
    left:-9999px;
    top:-9999px;
    list-style-type:none;
    color: white;

}

#myMenu li:hover ul {
    left: 0;
    top:30px;
    color: white;
}

#myMenu li:hover ul li a {
    padding:5px;
    display:block;
    text-indent:15px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;

}
#myMenu li:hover ul li a:hover { 
color: #fff;

    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hY2VF/1/

When you highlight 'Games' I want my secondary unordered list to appear, the same width as the list element above it, then all elements within that list just to appear under one another, but they are staying on the same line no matter what I change.

I'm not that great at using position: absolute, because if I could use float: left, I could just make them width 192px, then float all the elements left and that would force them onto a new 'line'.

Hm, any assistance at all would be great.

Comment: you need to watch out for your specificity, try adding classes or make sure you only style the elements you want to: http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/hY2VF/3/.  in your example your sub `li` are floated left because of your top level `li` styles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add this to your css: 
A `float:none;` *(so the effects of the previous float will be reset)*. 
Use `width:100%;` to set the width as the same width as the `<li>` add this to `#myMenu li:hover ul li{}` 
And than add `left: -40px;` *(You can tweak this)* on the `#myMenu li:hover ul{}` to get it directly under it.

```
#myMenu li:hover ul {
    left: -40px;            /* add this line */
    top:30px;
    color: white;
    width:100%;             /* add this line */
}
```

And add this new part (with the `float:none;`):

```
#myMenu li:hover ul li{
    float:none;       
    width:100%;         
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hY2VF/2/)** Your fiddle updated

Answer (score 0):

Use this I think useful for you.

```
#myMenu li:hover ul li a {
display:inline-block;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an updated version of your CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/hY2VF/4/

This is the most important change:

```
#myMenu li ul li {
    clear:both;
    width:auto;
    display:block;
}
```

`width:auto` releases the width restriction set in `#myMenu li {`.

Answer (score 0):

I have made new CSS.Just Check it out.I hope it'll work.

```
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/z6QrC/)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. just add one class in Main ul

Html

```
<ul id="myMenu">
    <li><a class = "link" href='#page1' Tooltip = "Home Page">Home</a>    </li>
    <li><a href='#page2'>Teams</a></li>
    <li><a href='#page3'>Games</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href='#page3'>CLG</a></li>
            <li><a href='#page3'>TSM</a></li>
            <li><a href='#page3'>C9</a></li>
            <li><a href='#page3'>SKT T1</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href='#page4'>Venues</a></li>
    <li><a href='#page4'>Battle</a></li>
</ul>
```

Css

```
ul.dropdown,
ul.dropdown li,
ul.dropdown ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 597;
    float: left;
}

ul.dropdown li {
    float: left;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    zoom: 1;
}

ul.dropdown li.hover,
ul.dropdown li:hover {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 599;
    cursor: default;
}

ul.dropdown ul {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 598;
    width: 100%;
}

ul.dropdown ul li {float: none;}

ul.dropdown ul ul {
    top: 1px;
    left: 99%;
}

ul.dropdown li:hover > ul {
    visibility: visible;
}

.dropdown li a {
    margin: 0 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
.dropdown li a:hover ul li {
    background: #000;
    opacity: 0.9;
}
```